# Run method on tap

Tags: java, android

I am trying to build an application, similar to cookie clicker, and I cannot get any onclick to work. I do not mind what it ends up having to do.

I've had a look around, and couldn't find anything that worked for me. This includes numerous DuckDuckGo searches, countless searches on-site, and my melted brain.

*mainactivity.java*

```
package scot.callumbarclay.tappygame;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


    private Button tap;
    private TextView tapCount;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tap = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        tapCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

    }
    int taps = 0;
    String start = "Taps: ";

    public void click(View v){
        taps = taps + 1;
        tapCount.setText(start + taps);
        System.out.println(start + taps);
    }

       @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is     present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

/*    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}*/
}
```

*activity_main.xml*

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"

>

    <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="150px"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="click" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Taps: 0"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

*android_manifest.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="scot.callumbarclay.tappygame" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

As you can see in *activity_main.xml*, I have tried `android:onclick`, which doesn't seem to have worked. For convienence, I have uploaded the source to [GitHub](https://github.com/CallumBarclay/Tappygame/).

**EDIT:** Added the onclick listener, doesn't seem to make much of a difference.

Comment: Where's your onclick listener? Or a button to click on, for that matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

Best way to do it:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            taps = taps + 1;
            tapCount.setText(start + taps);
        }
});
```

Comment: This hasn't worked for me so far, I've tried this with the button in all three "layers"(different positions in the component tree). I have edited it into the code now.

Comment: With the `tap.setOnClickListener`, it "`cannot resolve symbol 'setOnClickListener'`" Could there be an import I am missing?

Comment: Be sure to remove android:onClick from the button in  your layout file.

Comment: Also, why is your button invisible? Remove that visibility tag too

Comment: It was invisible so that the text could... It has been changed, I was trying to use the designer like one might use Photoshop.

Comment: It's still receiving the `cannot resolve symbol 'setOnClickListener'` error, and I cannot see what on earth is causing it.

Comment: I've managed to get it to work, alas. Not sure what I did, though.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just write an OnClickListener? I, personally, don't like Android Studio's "OnClick" paremeter. In the event you don't know how to set an onClickListener:

```
view.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    public void onClick(View v){
        taps++; //NOTE: You did taps = taps+1
        //This is the same thing as that
        //Everything else in your clicked method
    }
 });
```

You should also change your ID's to something that isn't `button` or `textView`

Also, don't use `System.out.println`. To print into the android "console" use

`Log.d("Whatever tag you want here", "Message")`

Lastly, why is there a button called `Tap` if the only thing you tap is the TextView?

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the logging. The reason I did `taps = taps + 1` was because I was unsure if `taps++` was a thing. I've not changed the ids, as this _should_ be an extremely basic application, with three elements.

Comment: With the `tap.setOnClickListener`, it "`cannot resolve symbol 'setOnClickListener'`"

Comment: Do you have `android.view.View` imported? I forgot about that part :l